# Clojure function to successively add vector elements (numbers)

Tags: clojure

```
(def coll [10 27 7 12])
```

Desired result is:

```
==> (10 37 44 56)
```

I tried:

```
(map #(+ % (next %)) coll)
```

with no success

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`reductions`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions) can do that:

```
(reductions + [10 27 7 12])
; → (10 37 44 56)
```

Comment: Kudos for finding a use-case for `reductions` beyond debugging your `reduce` function. ;-)